# Radio button value in VBS

Tags: forms, function, checkbox, vbscript, radio-button

I'm trying to read the value of a radio button in VBS and I am coming up with the following error:

**Type mismatch: 'phase'**

I am getting this error after I've put the radio buttons in a form in order to enable/disabled the checkbox depending on the first radio button.

Any help much appreciated!

MY CODE (not the whole code, just the faulty part. Sub RunScript is ran by a button):

```
<head>
</head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Sub RunScript

Dim currentphase

If phase(0).Checked Then
currentphase = phase(0).Value
End If

If phase(1).Checked Then
currentphase = phase(1).Value
End If


If currentphase = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select the phase.",48,"Error"
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub


</SCRIPT>

<body>
<form name="phaseform" action="" >
<input type="radio" name="phase" value="1" id="phase" onclick="checkbox(0)"/><label for="phase1">Phase 1</label>
<input disabled id=inorout type="checkbox" name="InorOUT" value="IN">LEGAL HOLD (<a href=javascript:RunLogFile()>?</a>) <br>
input type="radio" name="phase" value="2" id="phase" onclick="checkbox(1)" /><label for="phase2">Phase 2 (after 17 days)</label>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function checkbox(val)
{
    if(val)
document.phaseform.InorOUT.setAttribute("disabled",val)
else
document.phaseform.InorOUT.removeAttribute("disabled",val)
}
</script>

</BODY>
```

Comment: Why are you using both javascript and vbscript on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by replacing phase(0).Checked with document.phaseform.phase(0).Checked

Another way:
http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/how-can-vbscript-retrieve-value-selected-html-radio-butto-help-151913911.html

```
Dim i

for i = 0 to document.phaseform.phase.length - 1
if document.phaseform.phase(i).checked then
currentphase = document.phaseform.phase(i).value
end if

next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me.

```
Sub RunScript
    Dim currentphase
    If phaseform.phase(0).Checked Then
        currentphase = phaseform.phase(0).Value
    End If
    If phaseform.phase(1).Checked Then
        currentphase = phaseform.phase(1).Value
    End If
    If currentphase = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select the phase.",48,"Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly! I finally figured it out a few hours ago and worked for me with "document.phaseform.phase(0).Checked" instead of just "phase(0).Checked"

Comment: Didn't try your way though but I'm sure it's working so... issue solved! Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You should first clean up HTML section (improper formatted tags, etc.): see the following corrected one

```
<form name="phaseform" action="">
    <input type="radio" name="phase" value="1" id="phase" onclick="checkbox(0)" />
    <label for="phase1">Phase 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled id="InorOUT" name="InorOUT" value="IN" />LEGAL HOLD (<a href=javascript:RunLogFile()>?</a>)
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="phase" value="2" id="phase" onclick="checkbox(1)" />
    <label for="phase2">Phase 2 (after 17 days)</label>
</form>
```

Second, I would recommend to use javascript instead of combination vbscript/javascript in one page.

Comment: Yes, the application is mainly composed of vbscript (95%) and a bit of javascript for the checkbox enabled by radio buttons.

Comment: Well, then use the corrected HTML section with both scripts. Just be aware, that the task could be completed with javascript only. Rgds,

Comment: Thanks Alex. Is there any VBS way to read the radio value inside the form? Something like "document.phaseform.phase.value" ?

Comment: I didn't use vbscript for pretty long time, so I don't have an immediate answer for that. Rgds,